# FQL returning Null value

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I am getting a NULL result for the following FQL query

```
$fql="SELECT uid, page_id from page_fan where uid=me()";
$user_frnd = $facebook->api("/fql?q = " . urlencode($fql));
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: Do you have the user_likes permission? Have you tried running it through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?

Comment: Yes. The query works fine on explorer and I have all the permissions as well

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$params = array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => "SELECT uid, page_id from page_fan where uid=me()",
);

//Run Query
$JSON = $facebook->api($params);
```